# Is it legal to use memset(…, 0, …) on an array of doubles?

Tags: arrays, c, double, standards, memset

Is it legal to zero the memory of an array of doubles (using `memset(…, 0, …)`) or struct containing doubles?

The question implies two different things:

1. *From the point of view of C standard:* Is this undefined behavior of not? (On any particular platform, I presume, this cannot be undefined behavior, as it just depends on the in-memory representation of floating-point numbers—that’s all.)
2. *From practical point of view:* Is it OK on Intel platform? (Regardless of what the standard is saying.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The C99 standard Annex F says:

> This annex specifies C language support for the *IEC 60559 floating-point standard. The
> IEC 60559 floating-point standard is specifically Binary floating-point arithmetic for
> microprocessor systems, second edition (IEC 60559:1989)*, previously designated
> *IEC 559:1989* and as *IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic
> (ANSI/IEEE 754−1985)*. *IEEE Standard for Radix-Independent Floating-Point
> Arithmetic (ANSI/IEEE 854−1987)* generalizes the binary standard to remove
> dependencies on radix and word length. IEC 60559 generally refers to the floating-point
> standard, as in IEC 60559 operation, IEC 60559 format, etc. An implementation that
> defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex. Where
> a binding between the C language and IEC 60559 is indicated, the IEC 60559-specified
> behavior is adopted by reference, unless stated otherwise.

And, immediately after:

> The C floating types match the IEC 60559 formats as follows:
>
> - The `float` type matches the IEC 60559 single format.
> - The `double` type matches the IEC 60559 double format.

Thus, since IEC 60559 is basically IEEE 754-1985, and since this specifies that 8 zero bytes mean 0.0 (as @David Heffernan said), it means that **if you find  `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined, you can safely do a 0.0 initialization with `memset`**.

Comment: So its IEEE754 unless the compiler documentation explicitly states otherwise?

Comment: Actually, as I understood it, it is the contrary: it may be anything, but if you find defined `__STDC_IEC_559__` you can be sure that it's IEC 60559 aka IEEE 754.

Answer (score 15):

If you are talking about IEEE754 then the standard defines +0.0 to double precision as 8 zero bytes. If you know that you are backed by IEEE754 floating point then this is well-defined.

As for Intel, I can't think of a compiler that doesn't use IEEE754 on Intel x86/x64.

Comment: What about all the mobile devices that people are developing for. Do they all use IEEE754?

Comment: Still, from a practical standpoint I don't think that anyone designing a floating-point format will ever make it such that setting a `double` to all zero will make it become problematic. `:)`

Answer (score 7):

David Heffernan has given a good answer for part (2) of your question.  For part (1):

The [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard makes no guarantees about the representation of floating-point values in the general case.  §6.2.6.1 says:

> The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

...and that subclause makes no further mention of floating point.

You said:

> (on a fixed platform, how can this UB ... it just depends of floating representation that's all ...)

Indeed - there a difference between "*undefined* behaviour", "*unspecified* behaviour" and "*implementation-defined* behaviour":

- "*undefined* behaviour" means that anything could happen (including a runtime crash);
- "*unspecified* behaviour" means that the compiler is free to implement something sensible in any way it likes, but there is no requirement for the implementation choice to be documented;
- "*implementation-defined* behaviour" means that the compiler is free to implement something sensible in any way it likes, and is supposed to document that choice (for example, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/C-Implementation.html#C-Implementation) for the implementation choices documented by the most recent release of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/));

and so, as floating point representation is *unspecified* behaviour, it can vary in an undocumented manner from platform to platform (where "platform" here means "the combination of hardware and compiler" rather than just "hardware").

(I'm not sure how useful the guarantee that a `double` is represented such that all-bits-zero is `+0.0` if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined, as described in Matteo Italia's answer, actually is in practice.  For example, [GCC never defines this](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/c99status.html), even though is uses IEEE 754 / IEC 60559 on many hardware platforms.)

Comment: I would just assume IEEE 754 since otherwise floating point behavior might as well be `rand()`.

Comment: Do all hand held devices use IEEE754 as floating point rep. Desktop may be relatively standard but the mobile device market is a bit more splintered.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it is unlikely that you encounter a machine where this has problems, you may also avoid this relatively easily if you are really talking of *arrays* as you indicate in the question title, and if these arrays are of known length at compile time (that is *not* VLA), then just initializing them is probably even more convenient:

```
double A[133] = { 0 };
```

should always work. If you'd have to zero such an array again, later, and your compiler is compliant to modern C (C99) you can do this with a compound literal

```
memcpy(A, (double const[133]){ 0 }, 133*sizeof(double));
```

on any modern compiler this should be as efficient as `memset`, but has the advantage of not relying on a particular encoding of `double`.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles to the same? I would expect the latter to allocate 133*8 bytes on the stack, `memset` them to 0 (either inline or with a call), then call `memcpy` in a naive implementation.

Comment: @R..: The same, probably not. And with the 133 I was perhaps exaggerating a bit. But for more reasonable values gcc and clang are able to transform this into just storing zeros. opencc and icc generate an extra copy, and there opencc seems to be the worst in generating a call to `memcpy`, indeed. I said *should* not *will* :)

Answer (score 1):

As Matteo Italia says, that’s legal according to the standard, but I wouldn’t use it. Something like

```
double *p = V, *last = V + N;  // N is count
while (p != last) *(p++) = 0;
```

is at least twice faster.

Comment: I seriously doubt it's faster, and would expect it to be much slower. `memset` is typically the most-optimized function in any C library implementation, for good reason.

Comment: It may not be faster, but it is safer and the speed difference will be negligible in most situations.

Comment: I tested the code before posting it (for N = 10 ^ 7, on a Linux machine) and seemed to be faster than memset(V, 0, N * sizeof(double)).

Comment: A memset is often inlined directly by the compiler and also implemented in the VPU, which mean it can clear 128 bits in each iteration. If your loop is faster you probably use a crappy compiler or have these optimizations switched off.

Comment: Tested on several machines running Ubuntu / Debian and it seems memset is faster if the area contains a lot of zeros already. I compiled my code with "gcc -o memsettest memsettest.c -O2".

Comment: This is wrong. Without optimizations, the `memset` will be faster. With optimizations, any modern compiler should generate the same code.

Answer (score 0):

It’s “legal” to use `memset`. The issue is whether it produces a bit pattern where `array[x] == 0.0` is true. While the basic C standard doesn’t require that to be true, I’d be interested in hearing examples where it isn’t!

It appears that setting to zero via `memset` is equivalent to assigning 0.0 on IBM-AIX, HP-UX (PARISC), HP-UX (IA-64), Linux (IA-64, I think).

Here is a trivial test code:

```c
double dFloat1 = 0.0;
double dFloat2 = 111111.1111111;

memset(&dFloat2, 0, sizeof(dFloat2));

if (dFloat1 == dFloat2) {
    fprintf(stdout, "memset appears to be equivalent to = 0.0\n");
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "memset is NOT equivalent to = 0.0\n");
}
```

Comment: The test is flawed: it does not distinguish `0.0` and `-0.0` which are different. A stronger proof is `if (!memcmp(&dFloat1, &dFloat2, sizeof dFloat1)) ...`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think the zeroing is "legal" (after all, it's zeroing a regular buffer), but I have no idea if the standard lets you assume anything about the resulting logical value. My guess would be that the C standard leaves it as undefined.