# using memset() in double type array

Tags: c++

I want to set all the index value to `-1` in a double array.
Here is my code :

```
double dp[505];
memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
cout<<dp[0]<<"\n";
```

But it is showing `nan` when i try to print its value.

What does `nan` mean?
Is it possible to use `memset()` in double array?

Comment: Is it C++ or C? Choose one. NaN means Not A Number.

Comment: @iharob Yes? Why not? Oh you mean it's obvious. My point was that OP must tag appropriately, not that I didn't know. It was rhetorical.

Comment: what does `nan` means ?

Comment: @AliAkber I already told you

Comment: @AliAkber http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it legal to use memset(,0,) on array of doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629853/is-it-legal-to-use-memset-0-on-array-of-doubles)

Comment: @keyser sorry. i didn't notice

Comment: @iharob I don't think this is a dupe. It appears to be legal to `memset` an array of `double`s to `0` because 8 zeroes is defined to be floating point `0.0`. `memset`'ting to -1 (i.e. `0xff`) is a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, you can write:

```
double initValue = -1;
std::fill_n(dp, 505, initValue);
```

memsetting a double array with a non-double value won't work.

Comment: What about a 2D array ?

Comment: Assuming it's a C style 2D array, e.g: `dp[10][10]`, it's the same. Pass `10*10` to `fill_n` as size.

Comment: `double dp[165][2];
fill_n(dp, 165*2, -1.0);`
`error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const double' to 'double [2]'`
Why is this error ?

Comment: Use `fill_n(&dp[0][0], 165*2, -1.0)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

`memset` operates on bytes, not floats, and a `double` with all bytes set to -1 does not equal -1. I think you're looking for `std::fill`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill(dp, dp + 505, -1.0);
```

Or, in C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::fill(std::begin(dp), std::end(dp), -1.0);
```

Comment: what can i do if dp is 2D array ?

Comment: You can interpret the 2D array as a flat array of height * width doubles (it looks the same in memory) and write `std::fill(arr2d[0], arr2d[0] + width * height, -1.0);`

Comment: when i'm trying to use fill(), it causing me error `error: macro "fill" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2`
but it works when i'm using @erenon's way

Comment: `fill` is not a macro. Probably you're using some other library that `#define`s a `fill()` macro that interferes with this.

Comment: what can i do to make it work ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582333/error-in-using-fill-and-fill-n-in-2d-double-type-array

Answer (score 5):

You have set each element of the array to be filled with the byte `0xFF` (i.e. the `char` representation of `-1`).

No floating point number is represented by a series of `0xFF` bytes, so on printing the `double`, you see `NaN` (i.e. 'not a number'). This is in apparent contrast to `memset`'ting the bytes to zero, which is legal as a string of 0 bytes is a `double` with value zero. See [Is it legal to use memset(,0,) on array of doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629853/is-it-legal-to-use-memset-0-on-array-of-doubles).

If you meant to set every entry to `-1.0` (i.e. a double), then use `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` in C++ or a loop in C, e.g.

```
int n;
for (n = 0 ; n < 505 ; n++)
    dp[n] = -1.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

From the man page of [`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset):

> The `memset()` function fills the first *n* bytes of the memory area pointed to by *s* with the constant byte *c*.

The problem is that you want to fill an array of `double`s with the constant `-1.0` but `sizeof(double) > 1` so `memset` actually fills in garbage which happens to end up as a [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

If you are using C++, the [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function is your friend.  Actually, since you are writing to your array for the first time, [`std::uninitialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill) would be correct.  Although for the builtin `double` type there should be no difference but it is always good to be precise.

```
constexpr std::size_t length = 505;
double values[length];
std::uninitialized_fill(values, values + length, -1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

`memset` sets bytes, so you get `double`-values where each byte is `-1`.

Instead in C++ use `std::vector`, then write

```
vector<double> dp( 505, -1.0 );
```

It's that simple.

---

If `dp` is a global vector and you need to set it to `-1` a number of times, then you can simply do this:

```
dp = vector<double>( dp.size(), -1.0 );
```

However, it's [generally not a good idea to use non-`const` global variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

---

Alternatively one can use `std::fill`, or just a loop, or just about any technique that still treat the `double` values as `double` values. But `std::vector` is preferable also for many other reasons than greatly simplifying the fill-it task. In particular a `std::vector` can be resized, it takes care of copying, and it automates the memory management, doing that part correctly and transparent to you.

Comment: i know it.
But what if dp is a global vector and i need to set dp values -1 a certain number of times

Comment: I'm no C++ guru, but I'd have written: `vector<double> dp( 505, -1.0 );`

Comment: @abligh: thanks, that may be more clear yes. improved.

Comment: @abligh you are right. I think it saves time.
because if i do as the answer says, there should be some time waste to convert decimal to float

Comment: @AliAkber: No there's no runtime cost (to convert from `-1` to `-1.0`), but there could be a programmer's time cost.

Comment: @Cheers what do you mean by programmer's time cost?

Comment: @AliAkber: I mean, someone not seeing at a glance what the declaration means. Maybe someone wasting time correcting the declaration. About 80% of programming is maintenance (if I recall the stats correctly, may have changed a little), so it's wise to write code that communicates as clearly as possible to maintenance programmers.

Comment: @Cheers it can be ..
let me say one thing how can i do this if dp is global array and i need to do it a number of times ?

Answer (score 0):

nan means not a number.

cant see why its not working.
maybe because precision is not set : (cout.precision(15);)

check this:
[How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

But im not sure at all it will works :o
i checked memset source code and there's no problem with negative :D

But it can be a problem with doubles :

```
memset(dst0, c0, length) void *dst0;
register int c0;
register size_t length;
```

Have you tried to compile with Werror flag ?

Answer (score -1):

Although answers for you question have been given, I just wanted you to note that 
        `sizeof(dp)`
outputs the number of bytes used to code the variable in memory.

In your case, dp is a pointer to a double. It will then be equal to the size of a pointer (4), no matter wether or not memery has been allocated.
sizeof(*dp) will output the size of a double (8).
In order to use the length of a

Comment: Wrong. "When sizeof is applied to the name of an array, the result is the number of bytes required to store the entire array".