# error in using fill() and fill_n() in 2D double type array

Tags: c++

When i'm trying to use fill() like following way, it causing me error :

```
double dp[165][2];
fill(dp, dp+165*2, -1.0);

error: macro "fill" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
```

It also causing error when i'm trying with fill_n() :

```
double dp[165][2];
fill_n(dp, 165*2, -1.0);

error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const double' to 'double [2]'
```

can you point out the problem here ?

Comment: What's `fill()` actually?

Comment: From the error, you can deduce that the fill method accepts only two parameters.

Comment: @πάντα it will set a particular value to every index of the array

Comment: @AliAkber _"it will set a particular value to every index of the array"_ If you use [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), may be yes.

Comment: i use `using namespace std;` after the header.

Comment: @AliAkber _"i use using `namespace std;` ..."_ That's one thing you never should do, it bites you in the back.

Comment: why ?
can you explain please

Comment: @AliAkber [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1870232)

Comment: Thanks :)
i didn't aware of the fact before

Comment: @kec That's not true, it'll still invoke the macro. Macros aren't namespace sensitive.

Comment: Note that in practice, just be careful. Is the world going to end if you put it into your small test program's .cpp file? No, but you might run into problems such as you did. If you are an expert C++ programmer who is also a bad typist, you'll be able to resolve such issues quickly, and thus it'd probably be okay for you. At the other extreme, putting this in a header file for a large, widely used library would be a disaster.

Comment: @Barry: I deleted it.

Comment: can i know, why i'm getting downvote please ?
shouldn't i ask the solution of a problem i'm facing ?

Comment: Well, I don't know why you are getting downvoted, but the answer that you've received does answer your question.

Comment: yes. of course.. i accepted it..
but getting downvote really disappointed me :(

Comment: I didn't downvote, but some interpret basic questions as reflecting a lack of effort. That'd be my guess.

Comment: @kec i know you didn't. It's okay. Actually i learn about fill() and fill_n() today. so i'm at basic level in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
std::fill(dp[0], dp[0] + 165 * 2, -1.0);
```

or

```
std::fill_n(dp[0], 165 * 2, -1.0);
```

should work in standard C++. The error about `fill` macro with two arguments suggests that something `#define`s a macro named `fill` that interferes with the C++ standard library, though. This is likely to break more things than just this, so you should look into it and see if there's something like the `NOMINMAX` macro that prevents `windows.h` from doing the same with `min` and `max` (which breaks `<limits>`).

The problem you run into is that the value type of`dp` is not `double` but `double[2]`, to which `-1.0` cannot be assigned. The above code uses the fact that a 2D array of doubles looks in memory just like a flat array of doubles, which means that by casting `dp` to `double*`, it can be filled just like a 1D array. `dp[0]` is just the easiest way to get a pointer to the first element of `dp` of type `double*`.

Addendum: Technically, `dp[0]` is of type `double[2]`, but this decays to `double*` when it is used. `dp` can only decay to `double (*)[2]` (pointer to array of two doubles).

Comment: Although there is an issue with iterating beyond one past the end of an array, which technically is undefined behaviour. So this code is UB, although it is difficult to imagine an implementation in which it wouldn't work.

Comment: There's a special dispensation in the standard for this scenario (e.g. 5.7 (7) in C++03); a pointer to one element past the end of an array will compare in the expected way to a pointer to an element in the array. The behavior is well-defined.

Comment: One past is fine, two past isn't.

Comment: But this code doesn't go two elements past the end of any array. (side note: correction: it's 3.9.2 (3); 5.7 (7) defines something related but different)

Comment: The length of `dp` is 165. There's a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015080/c-c-is-this-undefined-behavior-2d-arrays).

Comment: Yes, but the members of `dp` contain a combined 165 * 2 doubles. The trick here to look at `dp[0]` as an array of 165 * 2 doubles, and `dp[0] + 165 * 2` is one past the end of that.

Comment: The point is that doing that is UB.