# Initializing array of fundamental types

Tags: c++, types, initialization

When creating an **array** of fundamental type such as :

```
double *aPtr = new double[10];
```

Is there a way of initializing it to a specific value? ((ex)-1)

Is creating a new class the only way?

Comment: You mean, initializing each one of the double in your array with a specific same value ?

Comment: yes sir. that's true Isuka.

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fill_n function can be what you are looking for. It will assign the n first values of your array with a specific value.

```
double *aPtr = new double[10];

std::fill_n(aPtr, 10, -1); // Fill the aPtr array with the value -1 for the 10 first values.
```

I do not know a specific way to fill it directly with one same value at declaration.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [std::fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

```
std::fill_n(aPtr , 10, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize fundamental types to be zero using uniform initialization.

```
double *aPtr = new double[10] {}
```

This will zero out the created array. You can also do this in C++03 using "()" instead of "{}".

However, this does not initialize all of the elements to a specific value. If you write `new double[10] {-1.0}` you will get an array with the first element being `-1.0` and the other nine - `0.0`.

You can specify all of the elements using an initializer list like this, but it is not scalable for large arrays. Instead, I believe that using `std::fill_n` or `std::fill` after the call to `new` is a better and simpler solution.

If you really want to not have a loop (even inside an algorithm) you can use variadic templates to generate an initializer list but that will require some work to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For such small arrays you can write explicitly

```
double *aPtr = new double[10] 
{ 
    ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1, ex -1 
};
```

However for a larger array you should use some standard algorithm as for example `std::generate`, `std::generate_n`, `std::fill`, `std::fill_n`, `std::for_each` or even some kind of loop.

For example

```
std::generate( aPtr, aPtr + 10, [value = ex - 1]{ return value; } );
```

or

```
std::generate_n( aPtr, 10, [value = ex - 1]{ return value; } );
```

or

```
std::fill( aPtr, aPtr + 10, ex - 1 );
```

or

```
std::fill_n( aPtr, 10, ex - 1 );
```

or

```
std::for_each( aPtr, aPtr + 10, [value = ex - 1]( auto &x ){ x = value; } );
```

If the compiler does not support the init capture you can write for example

```
std::generate( aPtr, aPtr + 10, [=]{ return ex - 1; } );
```

Comment: I *think* that when the OP wrote "ex -1" he means "for example, -1" - I could be wrong though...

Comment: @PaulR I think that it is not very important.:)

Comment: True - I just thought it might be a little confusing for anyone else reading this.

Answer (score -1):

if u want to initialize array of double and set values to 0 u can use:

`double* aPtr = (double*)calloc(10,sizeof(double));`

if u want set value of elements after decleration u can use:

`double *aPtr = new double[10];`
`memset(aPtr,value,size);`

same question and ur answer in detail:

[using memset in double type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581320/using-memset-in-double-type-array)

Comment: The question is on planet C++ not C

Comment: Or `double *aPtr = new double[10]();`

Comment: c & c++ dosn't have defference in memory allocation,after u use `calloc` u can call aPtr[1] = 10. for c++ i link to an answer