# How to initialize arrays in 2 ways using loop and memset?

Tags: c, arrays, function, memset

I am trying to answer a question in my C programming book, but I am not sure if my answer is correct.
The book doesn't provide any answers though. I am new to C programming, and any help will be appreciated.
 
Question:
 
Assume you have declared an array as follows:

```
float data[1000];
```

Show two ways to initialize all elements of the array to 0.
 
Use a loop and an assignment statement for one method, and the memset () function for the other.

**my current code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float data[1000]; 

main(){
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < 1000; count++){
        scanf("%f", &data[count]);
    }
    for (count = 0; count < 1000; count++){
        printf("Array %i: %f\n", count, data[count]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `memset` and assignment-in-a-loop is **not initialization.**

Comment: C Standard doesn't define that a floating point having all bits set to zero will have a value of 0.0f. Here is a correct way to do it using memcpy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630273/4082723.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points to help you get started:

- You're trying to set all items to `0`. `Scanf` requires you to input all values. This isn't necessary as you could just set them to `0` with `data[count]=0.0f;` inside of that for loop.
- `memset` is a function that will do something similar for you (including the for loop). Have a look at the documentation of [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/):

> memset
>
> void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
>
> Fill block of memory Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory
>   pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned
>   char).
>
> Parameters
>
> - ptr:
>     Pointer to the block of memory to fill.
> - value: 
>     Value to be set. The value is passed as an int, but the function fills the block of memory using the unsigned char conversion of this value.
> - num:
>     Number of bytes to be set to the value.
>     size_t is an unsigned integral type.

You should notice that memset only works with bytes. So you can use it to set a float to `0`, as it consists of 4 bytes that are all `0`, but you cannot set it to `1` for instance. But as notices by other users, this just happens to be so on most hardware.

Comment: Also notice (it is not a solution but a fact) just by having `data` defined as an `external` (i.e global) variable in C it is already initialized with its bytes in 0 as if you had used `memset()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(data,0,sizeof(data));
```

can be used to assign all the elements of the array to 0

Comment: There seems to be somebody who is downvoting all answers, just don't pay attention.

Comment: @JensGustedt do stackexchange has any mechanisim to detect such downvoters ?

Comment: Note that `sizeof` is not a function, so that can be written as just `memset(data, 0, sizeof data);`.

Comment: @unwind Even the reference manual says it can be used in either of ways `sizeof(data)` is totally fine IMO http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: @Gopi Why are you quoting a C++ document in a C question? And of course it works, but it works just because the argument is an expression (the expression `data`) that is put inside parentheses, which of course is also an expression, i.e. `(data)`. People write it like a function call though, which is confusing and which is something I tend to point out.

Comment: @unwind Just wanted to show that the `sizeof operator` can be used in both the syntax.

Comment: @Mr.32, yes, there is such a detection. But it can't be perfect.

Comment: @unwind You can either use `sizeof(any)` *or* `sizeof(any)`,`sizeof var`. The former variant is more consistent and readable.

Comment: @2501 I think I didn't understand what you were trying to say, sorry.

Comment: @unwind No problem. I suggest you look up topics on readability and consistency.

Comment: @2501 Why did you introduce two new names (`any` and `var`), and what do you mean by the part after the "*or*"? I didn't fail to understand the concepts of readability and consistency, I failed to understand the "variants" you were talking about.

Comment: @unwind Two different styles separated by *or*. Try coding examples with both styles and you will see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

> Show two ways to initialize all elements of the array to 0.  Use a
>   loop and an assignment statement for one method,  and the memset ()
>   function for the other.

1) Using for loop and assignment statement

```
for(i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    data[i] = 0.0f;
```

2) Using memset function

```
memset(&data,0,sizeof(data));
```

---

Short and simple way supported by c99 spec

```
float data[1000] = {0.0f};
```

declare array like this.

Comment: Sure, but (read the question) it's not listed in the exercise under "Use".

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are at least three methods.:)

```
// first
float data[1000] = { 0.0f };

// second
size_t i;
for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) data[i] = 0.0f;

// third
memset( data, '\0', sizeof( data ) );
```

You can also add one more method in C99

```
// forth
float data[1000] = { [0] = 0.0f };
```

In C++ you could use also the following declaration

```
float data[1000] = {};
```

or

```
float data[1000] {};
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is a need for `scanf("%f",&data[count]);` instead you can directly assign it with `data[count]=0;`

and if you use the `memset()` function you can set value to zero directly to an array `memset(data,'0',1000);`