# memset on float array does not fully zero out array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have some array,

```
float *large_float_array;
```

that I calloc and attempt to memset after a loop

```
large_float_array = (float*)calloc(NUM, sizeof(float));

// .. do stuff with float array

memset(large_float_array, 0, sizeof(large_float_array);

// .. do other stuff
```

but it seems `large_float_array` is not actually zero'd out. Why is this? Is this due to the special properties of floating point numbers? If so, I'm wondering how I could fix this.

P.S. does `calloc` actually work here too?

Comment: I just found [this](https://mackiemathew.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/dont-use-memset-for-initializing-floats-or-doubles/) , provides some insight into my question.

Comment: `memset(large_float_array, 0, sizeof(large_float_array);` does not compile.  Always kind to post true code.

Comment: C does not mandate that floating-point be ieee754 specifically. As such I believe there is no guarantee in the standard that `0.0f` be bitwise-zero.

Comment: `large_float_array = (float*)calloc(NUM, sizeof(float));` --> `large_float_array = calloc(NUM, sizeof *large_float_array);`

Comment: So is the consensus that memset on floating point arrays is ok, as long as I specify the right size? EDIT: @chux why should that be changed?

Comment: @Syntactic Fructose Using `memset(ptr, 0, ...` after `ptr = calloc(...)` is redundant.

Comment: @chux see my comment, I said ``do stuff with large array``, so pretend I filled it with stuff and now need to memset it

Comment: As [@AlexD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555614/memset-on-float-array-does-not-fully-zero-out-array#comment62600079_37555614) comment, your code is using the size of a pointer and not the size of a `float`.  Using `arge_float_array = calloc(NUM, sizeof *large_float_array);` avoids that problem regardless what type `large_float_array` points to.

Comment: There are 3 issues here: valid code, correct allocation and the question if `memset(some_float_ptr, 0,,...)` is as good as setting all `float` array elements to `0.0f`.  Until problem #1,#2 is fixed.  the 3rd issue is moot.

Comment: If code wants to quickly zero fill a `float` array, use a loop.  If that is not fast enough, code could use a helper function that repeatedly calls `memcpy()` to fill the large array with any `float` constant.

Comment: `memset(large_float_array, 0, sizeof(large_float_array);` (compiler error and wrong size) --> `memset(large_float_array, 0, NUM * sizeof *large_float_array);`  Still better to use a loop.

Answer (score 12):

Since `large_float_array` is a pointer, you cannot use `sizeof(large_float_array)` to specify the number of bytes to clear: `sizeof(large_float_array)` is just the size of the pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes. To clear the whole array, you must write:

```
memset(large_float_array, 0, NUM * sizeof(float));
```

or

```
memset(large_float_array, 0, NUM * sizeof(*large_float_array));
```

Note that `memset` sets the memory to all bits zero. The C standard does not guarantee that all bits zero be a representation of `0.0`, But in all current architectures it is the case, so it will work as expected.

The strictly conforming way to clear your array is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    large_float_array[i] = 0;
}
```

If the target systems represents `0.0` as all bits zero, modern compilers will optimize the above loop as a call to `memset` as can be verified with [Goldbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/iRyGB8).

PS: under the same assumption, `calloc()` would be a better choice: the block returned is initialized to all bits zero and for large sparse matrices, allocating via `calloc()` may actually be more cache efficient on many systems.

Comment: For those interested in the legality aspect of memset'ing a float, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629853/is-it-legal-to-use-memset-0-on-an-array-of-doubles) the link for that.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use memset because it accepts `int` as value type, but float may be stored in different way, so you should use a regular cycle

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    large_float_array[i] = 0.;
}
```

Comment: You should use `size_t` instead of `int` for `i`, as `NUM` could be larger that `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie does C have the `size_t` type?

Comment: Yes it does. It is defined in `<stdlib.h>` (among other places).

Comment: Much better answer.

Comment: And to avoid some bugs caused by unsigned types, you may want to change to the non-C-Standard but POSIX-Standard `ssize_t` which is a signed `size_t` and is defined in `<sys/types.h>`.

Comment: @LibertyPaul: *You can't use `memset` because it accepts `int` as value type*. `memset` does take an `int` argument, but it only uses the value converted as an `unsigned char`. Using `memset` to set an array of `int` would pose a similar problem as for an array of `float`: it would be fine to set the elements to `0`, and some other very specific values, but inappropriate for the general case.

Comment: You can do it (using correct sizes - see top answer) - and it will work at least on all x86/x64/ARM/SPARC/Power CPUs (and actually, on all CPUs which implement IEEE754). While in theory there can be a CPU which doesn't do it (or a compiler which doesn't use CPU and simulates floats itself) - I never ever heard of such an abomination.

Answer (score 3):

The effect of intializing memory area by `calloc` and using `memset` function with `0` value is actually the same. In other words, `calloc` is no more "type-wise" than `memset`. They both just set memory with all bits zero*.

C11 (N1570) 7.22.3.2/2 *The calloc function*:

> The `calloc` function allocates space for an array of nmemb objects,
>   each of whose size is size. The space is initialized to all bits zero.<sup>296)</sup>

Footnote 296 (informative only):

> Note that this need not be the same as the representation of
>   floating-point zero or a null pointer constant.

---

*) It's conceivable that `calloc` could return address of memory location that is already pre-initialized with zeros,  thus it may be faster than `malloc + memset` combo.

Answer (score 1):

Post has multiple issues.

Following does not have balanced `()`.  Unclear what OP's true code may be.

```
memset(large_float_array, 0, sizeof(large_float_array);
```

Assuming the above simple used another `)`, then code was only zero filling a few bytes with zero as `sizeof(large_float_array)` is the size of a pointer.

```
memset(large_float_array, 0, sizeof(large_float_array));
```

OP likely wanted something like which would zero fill the allocated space with zero bits.  This will bring the allocated memory into the same state as `calloc()`.

```
memset(large_float_array, 0, NUM *sizeof *large_float_array);
```

Code *should* use the following.  A good compiler will optimize this trivial loop into fast code.

```
for (size_t i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
  large_float_array[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

---

A way to use the fast `memcpy()` is to copy the `float` into the first element of the array, then the first element to the 2nd element, then the first 2 elements to elements 3 & 4, then the first 4 elements to elements 4,5,6,7 ...

```
void *memset_size(void *dest, size_t n, const char *src, size_t element) {
  if (n > 0 && element > 0) {
    memcpy(dest, src, element);  // Copy first element
    n *= element;
    while (n > element) {
      size_t remaining = n - element;
      size_t n_this_time = remaining > element ? element : remaining;
      memcpy((char*)dest + element, dest, n_this_time);
      element += n_this_time;
    }
  }
  return dest;
}

float pi = M_PI;
float a[10000];
memset_size(a, 10000, &pi, sizeof pi);
```

As with all optimizations, consider clearly written code first and then employ candidates such as the above in the select cases that warrant it.