# A C program meant to find the product of matrices isn't working

Tags: c, matrix

The lines of codes that come after the input of the elements of the matrix 'b' are not being executed. Also the nothing happens on pressing the enter button.
I wanted t know if this is a logic error or a semantic error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],i,j,k,m1,m2,n1,n2;
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m1,&n1);
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m2,&n2);
    //test for eligibility of matrices for multiplication
    if(n1==m2)
    {
        //input of the elements of matrix a
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix a: ");
        for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
        //Input of the elements of the matrix b
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix b: ");
        for(i=0;i<m2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
                scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
        //calculating the result of multiplication of matrices 'a' and 'b'
        printf("The result of multiplication of 'a' and 'b' is: ");
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m2;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<n2;k++)
                {
                    c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                    scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        //print the resultant matrix
        for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
            {
                printf("%4d",c[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        printf("The matrices are not eligible for multiplication");
}
```

Comment: `c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];` -- what's the value of `c[i][j]` at the first iteration *before* you assign something to it? `scanf("%4d",&c[i][j];` what does this do exactly?

Comment: I am very sorry for the mistake due to oversight. But even after the correction I am getting the same exact result as before.

Comment: What correction? Edit your question so that it contains up-to-date code.

Comment: You mean I need to initialize the elements of the matrix 'c' to zeroes.

Comment: Boy, there are _syntax errors_ in the code posted. (#7, #35), it's not even compiling...

Comment: You are using wrong variables in your loop. It should be m1 instead of  n1 and n2 instead of m2 and n1 or m2 instead of n2!

Comment: Also, on line 35, there is a `scanf`. Why?

Comment: Yes you do have to initialize everything you use. If you did, please edit the code in your question so that it's up to date. What's about the `scanf`?

Comment: You also should say `int main()` rather than just `main()`.

Comment: You keep editing that `scanf` but what does it *do*?

Comment: @n.m. There were two missing `"`-s, but in the 2nd edit they were introduced.

Comment: I have edited the code as per the suggestions of @n.m. and Koshinae. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for helping me out at the cost of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I took the time to fix it up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // New, for memset()

int main(void) // "Proper" signature
{
    int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],i,j,k,m1,m2,n1,n2;
    memset(c, 0, 100); // New, Ug Lee way of zeroing of the array
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m1,&n1);
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&m2,&n2);
    //test for eligibility of matrices for multiplication
    if(n1==m2)
    {
        //input of the elements of matrix a
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix a: ");
        for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n1;j++)
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
        //Input of the elements of the matrix b
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix b: ");
        for(i=0;i<m2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
                scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
        //calculating the result of multiplication of matrices 'a' and 'b'
        printf("The result of multiplication of 'a' and 'b' is: \n");
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m2;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<n2;k++)
                {
                    c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                    // scanf removed
                }
            }
        }
        //print the resultant matrix
        for(i=0;i<m1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
            {
                printf("%4d ",c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n"); // New, add newline
        }
    }
    else
        printf("The matrices are not eligible for multiplication");
}
```

The algorithm itself is fundamentally good. Your next step is to improve the code to use `calloc` for array allocation for the exact size you need for the matrices.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know of the alternate way of initializing the array to zero.

Comment: @ChetanPujar Remember, that when you use `calloc`, it specifically does the zeroing out, but the other `*alloc`-s do not.

Comment: Note: `calloc` zeroes all **bits**. For integers this also means to set the values to zero (they are defined that way), but that is not necessarily true for other types like floating point or pointers (_null pointer_). Oh, and: code-only answers are not really helpful to OP, less other readers.

Comment: What do you mean with "tried without it"? That's why I clearly wrote that it is fine for integers as used here. Btw., `memset` has the same issue.

Comment: And for the `memset` issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630036/357403 by this, I assume we can do it.