# Is there a way to clear arrays completely?

Tags: c, arrays

"I am trying to find the size of the 'list[34]' array but it is being set by random numbers when the program is being initialised. I cannot remove the rand() function in main because that is part of the question and is just added back in by the solution checker when I submit.

I have tried setting all the values in the array to '0' but that throws out the 'list_size' variable if the list is shorter than 35 values since the list is just filled with whatever is parsed into it followed by '0' in all other values.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

//  Declare Global variables here.
double list[34];
int list_size;

void array_stats() {
    //  Insert your solution here.

    for(int i = 0; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &list[i]);

        list_size = i;
        if (list[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
// Simulate the test setup process.
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 34; i++ ) {
        list[i] = rand();
    }
    list_size = rand();

    // Call submitted code.
    array_stats();

    // Display contents of array list.
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        printf("%f ", list[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Item count: %d\n", list_size);

    return 0;
}```

Expected result for an empty string (echo '' | file_name) is 0
Actual result for an empty string (echo '' | file_name) is 34
````

Comment: In your code: `for(int i = 0; i <= 35; i++)` you're using a wrong array length. Should be `for(int i = 0; i < 34; i++)`

Comment: Also, `for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)` might be out of bounds, since `list_size` is a random number (`list_size = rand();`) and it might be bigger then 34 (longer then the memory buffer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you you whould have used `int` datatype in your array:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

But since your are not, it get's a bit tricky and to clear a double array the best way is:

```
double list[34];
for (size_t i = 0; i < list; ++i)
  arr[i] = 0.0;
```

Theoretically, you should be safe using memset for floats and doubles, but see the caveats in the answers at [Is it legal to use memset(,0,) on array of doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629853/is-it-legal-to-use-memset-0-on-array-of-doubles) in case you have a non-standard floating point implementation.

Comment: It is coming up with a segmentation fault if I try your second solution

Comment: @BarrJ - I think you meant `(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); ++i)` .. or `for (double *p = list; p < *((&list)+1); ++p) *p = (double)0.0;`